# Optional argument in \newcommand with subscript and superscript

Tags: macros, superscripts, mathbb

I want to define a macro with an optional argument that will work with superscript and subscript in math mode.
e.g. `\binaryB{\alpha}` will result into `\mathbb{B}^{\alpha}`([image]) and `\binaryB` will result into simply `\mathbb{B}`([image]).

I have defined my macro as follows:
    `\newcommand*{\binaryB}[1][]{\mathbb{B}^{#1}}`.

But unfortunately, the superscript does not work. It is showing as:
[image]

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Try `\binaryB[\alpha]` ... The optional argument needs `[]` not `{}` ... You gave just a command without optional argument and `\alpha` comes just as a grouped `\alpha` ... not as a part of your commend

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried that, and that works. I am looking for something that will use braces for nonempty argument. `\binaryB{\alpha}` or `\binaryB`. Does Latex understand that? Otherwise I have to change a whole bunch of lines in my document.

Comment: It's possible to do, but not standard (TeX is Turing-complete so anything computable is *possible*). It would be a lot easier to just change your input.

Comment: What's the advantage of `\binaryB{\alpha}` over `\binaryB^{\alpha}`?

Comment: @egreg Well, it can encapsulate the notation, so that if the author wants to change it at a later time (e.g., to a subscript instead), they can do so from a single control point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Practically, an optional argument delimited by `{` and `}` breaks the (la)tex conventions, hence is strongly not recommended.
- Technically, the required syntax can be implemented as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\binaryB}{
  \mathbb{B}
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\sp}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \binaryB \qquad \binaryB{\alpha}
\]
\end{document}
```

With `xparse` package, the same command can be defined as

```
\NewDocumentCommand \binaryB {g}
  {
    \mathbb{B}\IfValueT{#1}{\sp{#1}}
  }
```

Note that `g`-type argument is marked as deprecated.